# Updating blank cells in access query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have about 40,000 rows and I am trying to update any blank cells
under the heading `Claim_Status` in `_Data table` to `"UNKNOWN"` or output `Claim_Status` in the table `"Status"`.  When I run the selection query, the number of rows shrink drastically to 20,000. The problem is that I need all 40,000 rows.

```
IIf(IsNull([_DATA]![Claim_Status]),"UNKNOWN",[Status]![Claim_Status])
```

For example,

I have a row that has a null(empty)cell under the ehading Claim_Status in the _Data table. When I run a query, I should still be including this row with "UNKNOWN" added to "Claim_Status" instead of an empty cell.

However, when I run the query, the row disappears and the total number of rows goes down to about 20,000. I am guessing that the rows that have disappeared have similar problems.

I am running a 'selection' query not 'update' query for your information.

Also, the output for Claim_Status is NOT the value from _Data table but instead, the one that is linked to it. Claim_Status column in _Data table is linked to Data_Status_Type in a different table called "Status" and the output is whatever that corresponds to the value from Data_Status_Type.

Is this what is causing the whole trouble?

Edited)

SQL code

```
   SELECT [_DATA].Claimant_Name, [_DATA].Account_ID, [_DATA].Claim_ID, [_DATA].Account_Name, [_DATA].Claim_Type, [_DATA].Coverage, [_DATA].Claim_Level, [_DATA].Claim_Count, [_DATA].File_Date, [_DATA].File_Year, [_DATA].Resolution_Date, [_DATA].Resolution_Year, Status.Claim_Status, [_DATA].Indemnity_Paid, Disease.Disease_Category, State.State_Filed, [_DATA].First_Exposure_Date, [_DATA].Last_Exposure_Date, [_DATA].Claimant_Employee, [_DATA].Claimant_DOB, [_DATA].Claimant_Deceased, [_DATA].Claimant_DOD, [_DATA].Claimant_Diagnosis_Date, [_DATA].Product_Type, [_DATA].Product_Line, [_DATA].[Company/Entity/PC], [Plaintiff Firm].Plaintiff_Law_Firm, [_DATA].Asbestos_Type, [_DATA].Evaluation_Date, [_DATA].Tier, [_DATA].Data_Source, [_DATA].Data_Source_Category, [_DATA].[Jurisdiction/County], [_DATA].Settlement_Demand, [_DATA].Jury_Verdict, [_DATA].Exposure_Site, [_DATA].National_Defendant_Firm, [_DATA].Local_Defendant_Firm, [_DATA].Expense_Amount, [_DATA].NCC_Expense_Amount, [_DATA].Non_NCC_Expense_Amount
FROM (((_DATA LEFT JOIN Disease ON [_DATA].Disease_Category = Disease.Data_Disease_Type) LEFT JOIN [Plaintiff Firm] ON [_DATA].Plaintiff_Law_Firm = [Plaintiff Firm].Data_Firm) LEFT JOIN State ON [_DATA].State_Filed = State.Data_State) LEFT JOIN Status ON [_DATA].Claim_Status = Status.Data_Status_Type
WHERE (((Status.Claim_Status)=IIf(IsNull([_DATA]![Claim_Status]),"UNKNOWN",[Status]![Claim_Status])));
```

Comment: Can you give us ~4 records and which records of those 4 aren't being selected that should have been, and your query?

Comment: Also can you give us the whole query, just to see if there's anything in there?

Comment: I have edited my post if you need more information please let me know

Comment: I am very confused by the following two statements `I am trying to update any blank cells...` and `I am running a 'selection' query not 'update' query...`  can you instead just post the entire SQL for your query?

Comment: IIf(IsNull([_DATA]![Claim_Status]),"UNKNOWN",[Status]![Claim_Status])
This line is what I wrote for Criteria in the query design

Comment: I added the SQL statement into the original post. Please check it out !

Comment: Couldn't you just set that fields default to be `UNKNOWN`?  Then you don't even have to deal with the null fields.

Comment: It's just that some fields have to be blank. Only the empty cells under "Claim_Status" should be changed from blank to "UNKNOWN"

Comment: Is `[_DATA]![Claim_Status] = [Status]![Claim_Status]`? Are they the same?

Comment: no.. I rephrased my question

Comment: My guess (without having your data) is that your `WHERE` clause is reducing/filtering the number of records you're seeing...

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you're after, which is to return all rows from the left-most table `[_DATA]`, and simply replace NULLs in `[_DATA]![Claim_Status]` with "UNKNOWN", then you should drop the `WHERE` clause, and add the field to your `SELECT` statement within the `Nz` function (http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php).  Here is the example SQL:

```
 SELECT Nz([_DATA]![Claim_Status], "UNKNOWN") As [_DATA_Claim_Status], [_DATA].Claimant_Name, [_DATA].Account_ID, [_DATA].Claim_ID, [_DATA].Account_Name, [_DATA].Claim_Type, [_DATA].Coverage, [_DATA].Claim_Level, [_DATA].Claim_Count, [_DATA].File_Date, [_DATA].File_Year, [_DATA].Resolution_Date, [_DATA].Resolution_Year, Status.Claim_Status, [_DATA].Indemnity_Paid, Disease.Disease_Category, State.State_Filed, [_DATA].First_Exposure_Date, [_DATA].Last_Exposure_Date, [_DATA].Claimant_Employee, [_DATA].Claimant_DOB, [_DATA].Claimant_Deceased, [_DATA].Claimant_DOD, [_DATA].Claimant_Diagnosis_Date, [_DATA].Product_Type, [_DATA].Product_Line, [_DATA].[Company/Entity/PC], [Plaintiff Firm].Plaintiff_Law_Firm, [_DATA].Asbestos_Type, [_DATA].Evaluation_Date, [_DATA].Tier, [_DATA].Data_Source, [_DATA].Data_Source_Category, [_DATA].[Jurisdiction/County], [_DATA].Settlement_Demand, [_DATA].Jury_Verdict, [_DATA].Exposure_Site, [_DATA].National_Defendant_Firm, [_DATA].Local_Defendant_Firm, [_DATA].Expense_Amount, [_DATA].NCC_Expense_Amount, [_DATA].Non_NCC_Expense_Amount
 FROM (((_DATA LEFT JOIN Disease ON [_DATA].Disease_Category = Disease.Data_Disease_Type) LEFT JOIN [Plaintiff Firm] ON [_DATA].Plaintiff_Law_Firm = [Plaintiff Firm].Data_Firm) LEFT JOIN State ON [_DATA].State_Filed = State.Data_State) LEFT JOIN Status ON [_DATA].Claim_Status = Status.Data_Status_Type;
```

That `WHERE` clause isn't having the desired effect because what it says is if `[_DATA]![Claim_Status]` Is Null then return rows where `Status.Claim_Status` = "UNKNOWN", otherwise return rows where `Status.Claim_Status` equals itself.  And, because you're including an outer joined table in your `WHERE` clause you're effectively turning that into an `INNER JOIN`.